# omit groups in pandas groupby based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sym': list('aaaaaabb'), 'key': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], 'x': [100, 100, 90, 100, 500, 500, 700, 700]})
```

I group them by `key` and `sym`:

```
groups = df.groupby(['key', 'sym'])
```

Now I want to check whether all `x` in each group are equal or not. If they are not equal, I want to delete it from the `df`. In this case I want to omit the first group.
This is my desired `df`:

```
   key sym    x
4    2   a  500
5    2   a  500
6    3   b  700
7    3   b  700
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`SeriesGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html) and compare by `1`, filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df.groupby(['key', 'sym'])['x'].transform('nunique').eq(1)]
print (df1)

  sym  key    x
4   a    2  500
5   a    2  500
6   b    3  700
7   b    3  700
```